# Set Variable to Child Node in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am really struggling with what appears to be a simple issue.  I'm working in React and trying to set a variable to the state which is passed.

Here is the JSON that is passed

```
{
  "id": "6",
  "FName": "Chris",
  "LName": "Baker",
  "Height": "6'2",
  "Meds": [
    {
      "MedicationName": "acetaminophen",
      "Doseage": "Take 2 daily with food",
      "NumRefills": 2,
      "RefillExp": "2017-05-31T15:38:50.02Z",
      "FirstPrescribed": "2017-05-31T15:38:50.02Z",
      "WFID": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am able to set variables at the parent level just fine for example....

```
class App extends ReactComponent {
  ....
  render() {
    return (
    ....
    <OverviewPane overview={this.state.PATIENT}/>
     ....
    );
   }
}
```

Then in the Overview Pane, I am able to set fields based on the data from the JSON as expected. (see below)

```
class OverviewPane extends ReactComponent {
      ....
      render() {
        return (
        ....
        <td>{this.props.overview.map(function(P){return <label key={P.id}> First Name: {P.FName}</td>
         ....
        );
       }
    }
```

However I am not able to get the Meds so what I try there is the following...

```
class App extends ReactComponent {
  ....
  render() {
    return (
    ....
    <MedicationsPane meds={this.state.PATIENT.Meds[0]}/>
     ....
    );
   }
}
```

And in the Medications Pane...

```
class MedicationsPane extends React.Component {  
...
  render () {
    return (
      <List>
            {this.props.meds.map(function(Meds) {
            return <ListItem justify='between' separator='horizontal' key={Meds.MedicationName}>{Meds.MedicationName}</ListItem>;
          })}
      </List>
    );
  }
}
```

When I do the above however I get the error "Cannot read prperty '0' of undefined.   Any idea how I can extract the Medications from the JSON?

Comment: Can you share where you actually calling your request or you are setting default state as the json object you have mentioned?As this.state.PATIENT is getting undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

`OverviewPane` component suggests that `this.state.PATIENT` as an array so accessing `Meds` as `this.state.PATIENT.Meds` will result result in `undefined`(unless there is a `Meds` property on the `PATIENT` array) and so is the error.

To avoid this, you can do

```
class App extends ReactComponent {
  ....
  render() {
    return (
    ....
    {this.state.PATIENT.map(p => {
      return (p.Meds && p.Meds.length > 0) ? <MedicationsPane meds={p.Meds}/> : null;
    })}
     ....
    );
   }
}
```

secondly, you are sending medication details to `MedicationsPane` as `overview` and accessing them as `this.props.meds`. Change them to same name.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `this.state.PATIENT` to `OverviewPane` as `overview`.

In `OverviewPane` you're mapping over `overview` which suggest that `this.state.PATIENT` is an array.

However, when using `MedicationsPane` you are treating `this.state.PATIENT` as an object that has `Meds` property. If `this.state.PATIENT` is an array, you should access `Meds` property as `this.state.PATIENT[PATIENTINDEX].Meds[0]`